# what are the macOS app requirements for the Finder share, open menu

Tags: macos, finder, info.plist

Using the Finder, my app is listed in the "Open with" contextual menu, but not always with its "Share" menu so I'm suspecting some property list for my app is missing or wrong, causing some file types to be filtered from appearing the Share menu.

What properties do I define to identify what file(s) type I can share and/or open for the Finder?

My share extension already has these:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, all I had to do was log out.

Not sure why "Open with" and "Share" menus are distinct but that's a question for another post.